# Wrap img in div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to wrap an image in a div element when the image is clicked. Once this is done, I would like to add a class attribute on the div. I'm looking for a utility in jQuery that could help achieve the first task.

```
$(img).on('click', function() {
   // wrap this image in div
})
```

While a jQuery implementation is preferable, vanilla dom scripting is ok as well.

Comment: Did you search `jquery wrap` ?

Comment: See the answer below, but yes, you need to lookup this first. Google search for: jquery wrap image in div will lead you to .wrap() API on the first link.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh thanks for the lead; you have no idea how many times I searched the wrong stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
```

The wrap function of jQuery should be your best bet. This would refer to the clicked  but you can be more precise if you want.

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code:

```
$(img).on('click', function() {
   $(this).wrap('<div></div>')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JQuery wrap` function  here is the [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
var img=document.getElementById('img1')
$(img).on('click', function() {
   $(this).wrap('<div class="newClass"></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img1">
```